# MySQL where clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

In all the samples they talk about a static string in the clause:

```
update ranking_data set ft_kw = NULL 
WHERE ranking_data.website = 'abc.com';
```

Okay but what if we want a dynamic string?

```
update ranking_data set ft_kw = NULL WHERE ranking_data.website = $website_name;
```

Which does not work. Single quote gets rid of the error msg but does not execute properly. ft_kw is never set, even a perfect match.

Can anyone give me the proper syntax on a variable string?

Comment: [How do i format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query(" update ranking_data set ft_kw = NULL WHERE ranking_data.website = ' " . $website_name . " ' " );
```

Comment: This was very close. When I removed the blank spaces, it works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding singlw quotes around $website_name:

```
{ mysql_query("update ranking_data set ft_kw = NULL WHERE ranking_data.website = '$website_name'");}
```

Comment: Why don't u echo the update statement and then manually run it against db?